# PHP cURL : Post to Facebook Page as Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I tried a sample code to post to Facebook page. But it is posting as myself. I have included Page_access_token.

permission granted is 'manage_pages' and 'publish_action'.
 Here is my code :

```
<?php

    $page_id='xxxx';
    $page_access_token='cccc';
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/{$page_id}/feed?message=Hello&access_token=".$page_access_token;
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $value = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $var_dump($value);

?>
```

Where am I going wrong ? How do I solve it ?
I want it to be posted as page. Thanks

EDIT:
My new code with /$PAGE_ID?fields=access_token:

```
<?php
  $page_id='xxx';
  $message='helloworld';
  $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$page_id}?fields=access_token";
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

  $json = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
  var_dump($json);
?>
```

This returns an error :

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(64) "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource."
    ["type"]=>
    string(14) "OAuthException"
    ["code"]=>
    int(210)
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Do I need to create the page_access_token from graph API explorer? or the above url is enough? How I am supposed to use User_access_token to get page_access_token ?

Comment: What do you get as return?

Comment: It returns an ID, something like this 
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1387602394895539_1390602811262164
)
The message gets posted to page , but as myself not as page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it gets posted as yourself, you are not using a Page Token. Debug your Token and see if the Page ID is listed - that´s how you know it´s a Page Token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Btw, you should use the new `publish_pages` permission to post to Pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes

Information about how to get Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: I tried both 'manage_pages' & 'publish_pages' too. Nothing gets posted if I use only those two. How to get the Page Token ? Do I need a User Token to get Page Token ?

Comment: That was a great link. But how can I achieve this with cURL ?

Comment: just do an api call to "/PAGE-ID?fields=access_token" with curl to get a page token.

Comment: ok. I tried this. But it returns me an error. I have posted my new code. Kindly check that and provide me a solution

Comment: I am really not getting how to implement it, as I am just in a learning stage. Tried all possible way I know.  It would be a great help for me if u can provide a code snippet. Thank you

Comment: code examples are in the facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/accounts

Comment: right now you are doing it completely wrong, you are trying to do a POST call to GET an access token, and you are trying to add a message to the call... you really need to understand what´s happening there with the graph api and curl...

Comment: ah ! I am completely stuck here. code examples in Facebook use PHP-SDK  library. But I want it in simple CURL code. What I am trying is wrong. Then how to do ?

Comment: i have added a third link, maybe that one helps you to understand

Comment: Yes,a great link. really took me to heaven.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
  $page_id='xxx';
  $message='helloworld';
$access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$page_id}/feed/?access_token=".access_token ."&message=".urlencode(message);
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

  $json = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
  var_dump($json);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please note that [code-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques). You could improve your answer by elaborating a bit.